# replace text using lookahead regex

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to modify a few lines of a text file.

```
# cat example.txt
tested
tests
testing
```

If the word 'test' is not followed by 'ed' or 's' then change it to word 'work'. The following exmpression is working as expected:

```
test(?!ed|s)
```

But it does not work in sed as like this...

```
# sed -r 's/test\(?!ed\|s\)/work/g' example.txt
tested
tests
testing
```

The expected output is:

```
tested
tests
working
```

I guess sed does not support lookahead or lookback. Is there any other easy linux command for this?

Comment: Can it be `test bla bla ed` OR `test bla bla etc etc s` also?

Comment: No. This is hunspell dictionary file having millions of english words (single word per line).  There can be 'testtest' but it is very rare and can be ignored. A few incorrectly changed words can be modified manually.

Comment: Works with Perl, `perl -pe's/test(?!ed|s)/work/g' filename`

Comment: So then why don't we simply ignore those which words we don't want like: `awk ('!/\ytested\y/ && !/\ytests\y/) && /\ytesting\y/{sub(/testing/,"working")} 1' Input_file`. I am yet to test it, it needs GNU `awk`.

Comment: Note, with that regex `testers` _is_ changed to `workers`.    (It disallows a match only when `ed|s` follow _immediately_)  Is that what you want? I guess it should be OK since it's the same as asked just for the word `tester` instead of `test`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
perl -pe's/test(?!ed|s)/work/g' filename
```

---

For Unicode (non-ASCII) text we need to enable support for it

```
perl -Mutf8 -CSAD -pe'...' filename
```

Here the [utf8 pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/utf8) is needed if there are literal non-ASCII characters in the source, while the other flags can be seen under [command switches in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches)

Comment: Does not seem to work with non-english text.

Comment: @shantanuo "_Does not seem to work with non-english text_" -- hm, shouldn't matter ... an example?  (But if by "non-english" you mean Unicode -- non-ASCII -- then we need to enable support for it, by passing suitable flags)

Comment: perl -pe 's/गुरु(?!कुल|कृप)/गुरू/g' anay_guru.txt > anay_guru_update.txt

Comment: @shantanuo Sorry, I forgot to state flags (!) -- you want `perl -‑CSAD -we'...'` for Unicode, and if the source (the program itself) contains literal unicode characters then we also need `utf8` pragme, so altogether `perl -Mutf8 ‑CSAD -we'...'` . Added to answer

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\<(test)(ed|s)?\>/\1\n\2/g;s/\<test(\S+)/work\1/g;s/\n//g' file
```

If a word optionally ends in a defined ending, insert a newline between the word and its allowed ending.

If the same word does not end in a newline, replace the word by `work`.

Remove all scaffolding newlines.